# Problem loading JS when creating and modifying an element

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I hope you can help me with these problems that I have with the execution of my JS, I have 2 problems that I will detail:

**WHEN CREATING**

I am using the `change` and `select` events to be able to know if I am selecting and changing an option from my question `combobox`. The problem is when I have selected the option 1 `SINGLE / MULIPLE ANSWER` of the question type. If when saving I do not have any `checkbox` selected from the available options, it will throw me the alert to select at least one option, so far everything works fine for me but when I select a `checkbox` from the options and try to save, the alert does not disappear. I've tried adding the event `checked` but it can't work for me. What I want to do is that when I save and I do not have an option selected, it throws me the alert message (this already does), and when I select an option, the alert disappears so that it allows me to save.
[image]
[image: CREATING2]

**WHEN MODIFYING**

The second problem occurs when I try to modify an element, the JS does not run, so that it can work I have to select another option and return to the previous one so that it can work.
[image: MODIFYING1]
[image: MODIFYING2]

**HTML**

```
<form id="dynamic-form" action="" method="post">
<div class="content">
    <div class="box box-success box-solid">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Evaluation</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="dynamicform_wrapper"> //where select and change applies
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Questions</th>
                            <th style="width: 500px;">Options</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 90px;">
                                <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                            </th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="container-items">
                        <tr id="0" class="item">//ID that I use to find the elements

                            <td class="question"> //where do i apply colspan
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="vcenter">
                                                <span class="panel-title-address">Nr: 1</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="vcenter">
                                                <input type="hidden" id="qquestion-0-id_question" name="qquestion[0][id_question]" value="28">                                        
                                                <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-type_id required">
                                                    <label class="control-label" for="qquestion-0-type_id">Question Type</label>
                                                    <select id="qquestion-0-type_id" class="form-control" name="qquestion[0][type_id]" onchange="">
                                                        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                                                        <option value="1" selected="">SINGLE / MULIPLE ANSWER</option> // OPTION 1
                                                        <option value="2">OPEN QUESTION</option> // OPTION 2
                                                    </select>
                                                    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                                                </div> 
                                                <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-title required">
                                                    <input type="text" id="qquestion-0-title" class="form-control" name="qquestion[0][title]" value="" maxlength="250" placeholder="Títle">
                                                    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                                                </div>                      
                                                <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-score required">
                                                    <input type="text" id="qquestion-0-score" class="form-control" name="qquestion[0][score]" value="" placeholder="Score" data-plugin-inputmask="inputmask_2fdcbd27">
                                                    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                                                </div>                                        
                                                <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-image">
                                                    <label class="control-label" for="qquestion-0-image">Image</label>
                                                    <input type="file" id="qquestion-0-image" class="empty-value" name="qquestion[0][image]">
                                                    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                                                </div>                                        
                                                <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-justify_answer">
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <label style="padding:5px;" for="qquestion-0-justify_answer">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="qquestion[0][justify_answer]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="qquestion-0-justify_answer" name="qquestion[0][justify_answer]" value="">
                                                        Do you want the answer to be justified?
                                                        </label>
                                                        <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div> 
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="clearfix"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td class="item-opcion">                                
                                <div class="dynamicform_inner">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">
                                                    <button type="button" class="add-opcion btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody class="container-opciones">
                                            <tr class="opcion-item">
                                                <td class="vcenter">
                                                    <input type="hidden" id="qoption-0-0-id_option" name="qoption[0][0][id_option]" value="">                
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <div class="form-group field-qoption-0-0-opcion_correcta required">
                                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                                    <label style="padding:5px;" for="qoption-0-0-opcion_correcta">
                                                                        <input type="hidden" name="qoption[0][0][opcion_correcta]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="qoption-0-0-opcion_correcta" name="qoption[0][0][opcion_correcta]" value="1">
                                                                    </label>
                                                                    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>                    
                                                        </span>
                                                        <div class="form-group field-qoption-0-0-title_option required">
                                                            <input type="text" id="qoption-0-0-title_option" class="form-control" name="qoption[0][0][title_option]" value="2" maxlength="250" placeholder="Opción">
                                                            <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                                                        </div>                
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px;">
                                                    <button type="button" class="remove-opcion btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>       
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-error-check required has-error" style="display: none;">
                                    <p class="help-block help-block-error">You must select at least 1 option as correct.</p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px; verti">
                                <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Modificar</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("change","select",function(){     
        if ($(this).val()== 2) {
            $('#0').find('.option-item').not(':first').remove(); //removed all entries found in
            $('#0').find('.option-item:first').hide(); 
            $('#0').find('.item-option').hide(); 
            $('#0').find('.question').attr('colspan',2);
        }else if ($(this).val()== 1){
            //var numberNotChecked = $('#0').find('.option-item input:checkbox:not(":checked")').length;
            var numberChecked = $('#0').find('.option-item input:checkbox:checked').length;
            $('#0').find('.container-options').append(newtr); //add input
            $('#0').find('.item-option').show(); 
            $('#0').find('.question').removeAttr('colspan',2);
            $( "#dynamic-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
                if(numberChecked > 0){
                    $('#0').find('.text-error-check').hide();
                    $('#0').find('.dynamicform_inner').removeAttr("style");
                } else {
                    $('#0').find('.text-error-check').show();
                    $('#0').find('.dynamicform_inner').css({'border':'2px solid #dd4b39','background-color':'white'});
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
       }});
```

Hope you can help me with these problems, I am not very good at using javascript or jquery. I thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so that it would be easy to understand where problem exist .

Comment: I have added and modified my code so you can review it
@Swati

Comment: Hi ,does below answer solve your problem ? You can upvote and accept it :)

Comment: Sorry I if not answer you before, I have been very busy these last months but your answer had a flexible point to be able to find the solution I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code you are using wrong selector to get total value of checked checkboxes.If you check your current jquery code its always giving `0` even if you checked any value. So , you can use `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` which will give you correct values of checked checkboxes.

Then , you have placed your `submit` event inside your change event that's the reason the warning shows for the first time but when you select some checkbox and again clicked save button it doesn't go away (also because of wrong selector) so i have separated it from the change event .

Also you have forget to show the `tr` which you have `hide()` when select-box value is `2` i.e : `item-option` so add `.show()` to it when value is `1`.

**Working Code** :

```js
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("change", "select", function() {

  if ($(this).val() == 2) {
    $('#0').find('.option-item').not(':first').remove(); //removed all entries found in
    $('#0').find('.option-item:first').hide();
    $('#0').find('.item-option').hide();
    $('#0').find('.question').attr('colspan', 2);
  } else if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    // $('#0').find('.container-options').append(newtr); //add input
    $('#0').find('.item-option').show();
    $('#0').find('.option-item:first').show(); //show option-item which is hidden
    $('#0').find('.question').removeAttr('colspan', 2);

  }
});

$("#dynamic-form").submit(function(event) {
  //getting all inputs which is under tr 
  var numberChecked = $('#0').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  console.log("No of checkbox checked=" + numberChecked)
  if (numberChecked > 0) {
    $('#0').find('.text-error-check').hide();
    $('#0').find('.dynamicform_inner').removeAttr("style");
     event.preventDefault();//remove this to submit
  } else {
    $('#0').find('.text-error-check').show();
    $('#0').find('.dynamicform_inner').css({
      'border': '2px solid #dd4b39',
      'background-color': 'white'
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  
  }
   
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form id="dynamic-form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box box-success box-solid">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Evaluation</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="dynamicform_wrapper"> //where select and change applies
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Questions</th>
                <th style="width: 500px;">Options</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width: 90px;">
                  <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                </th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="container-items">
              <tr id="0" class="item">//ID that I use to find the elements

                <td class="question"> //where do i apply colspan
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="vcenter">
                          <span class="panel-title-address">Nr: 1</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="vcenter">
                          <input type="hidden" id="qquestion-0-id_question" name="qquestion[0][id_question]" value="28">
                          <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-type_id required">
                            <label class="control-label" for="qquestion-0-type_id">Question Type</label>
                            <select id="qquestion-0-type_id" class="form-control" name="qquestion[0][type_id]" onchange="">
                              <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                              <option value="1" selected="">SINGLE / MULIPLE ANSWER</option> // OPTION 1
                              <option value="2">OPEN QUESTION</option> // OPTION 2
                            </select>
                            <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-title required">
                            <input type="text" id="qquestion-0-title" class="form-control" name="qquestion[0][title]" value="" maxlength="250" placeholder="Títle">
                            <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-score required">
                            <input type="text" id="qquestion-0-score" class="form-control" name="qquestion[0][score]" value="" placeholder="Score" data-plugin-inputmask="inputmask_2fdcbd27">
                            <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-image">
                            <label class="control-label" for="qquestion-0-image">Image</label>
                            <input type="file" id="qquestion-0-image" class="empty-value" name="qquestion[0][image]">
                            <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-justify_answer">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                              <label style="padding:5px;" for="qquestion-0-justify_answer">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="qquestion[0][justify_answer]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="qquestion-0-justify_answer" name="qquestion[0][justify_answer]" value="">
                                                            Do you want the answer to be justified?
                                                            </label>
                              <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="clearfix"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
                <td class="item-option">
                  <div class="dynamicform_inner">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Description</th>
                          <th class="text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="add-option btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody class="container-opciones">
                        <tr class="option-item">
                          <td class="vcenter">
                            <input type="hidden" id="qoption-0-0-id_option" name="qoption[0][0][id_option]" value="">
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                <div class="form-group field-qoption-0-0-opcion_correcta required">
                                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                                        <label style="padding:5px;" for="qoption-0-0-opcion_correcta">
                                                                            <input type="hidden" name="qoption[0][0][opcion_correcta]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="qoption-0-0-opcion_correcta" name="qoption[0][0][opcion_correcta]" value="1">
                                                                        </label>
                                                                        <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>                    
                                                            </span>
                              <div class="form-group field-qoption-0-0-title_option required">
                                <input type="text" id="qoption-0-0-title_option" class="form-control" name="qoption[0][0][title_option]" value="2" maxlength="250" placeholder="Opción">
                                <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px;">
                            <button type="button" class="remove-opcion btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                          </td>

                        </tr>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group text-error-check required has-error" style="display: none;">
                    <p class="help-block help-block-error">You must select at least 1 option as correct.</p>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px; verti">
                  <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Modificar</button>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
```